# How to insert in database after getting information in another page

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

i try to get information in another page which works fine, the only facing problem is that i can't insert in database the information i get, for example:

This is the link i use which works fine.

**index.php**

```
<a href="http://example.com/q.php?url= '. $row['url'] .'&title='. $row['title'] .'" target="_blank">Edit</a>
```

**q.php**

```
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // This is working fine.
    $title = $_GET['title']; 

mysql_query("insert into test_insert (title,ip) values('$title','$ip_address')")
            or die(mysql_error());

$title = $_GET['title']; // Not working
// If i delete this row above and replace with below it works.
$title = 'test';         // This is working and puts (test) in row title
```

I can't understand why i can show the information in q.php with:

```
<?php echo $_GET['title']; ?>
```

And can't insert it in database, what is wrong with this ?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your table schema for this..it may be possible it has different data type or has problem with limit

Comment: Don't ever use raw user data in your queries! Use prepared statements instead. In that case it should also fix your problem.

Comment: What about `?url` how is that being used? You're only passing `$_GET['title']` - Use the `&&` operator.

Comment: I hate to be that person but, What do you mean with`Not working` at `$title= $_GET['title']`? Is it giving an error? Is it empty?

Comment: When you click on the link, is the text after `&title=` correct?

Comment: Everything is working fine the only problem is that i can't insert $title = $_GET['title']; in row title

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined index: title. But that is because i need to use $_SESSION to keep the values after submit, i think